# How to disable onClick splash in Flutter WebView

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I'm new to flutter and would appreciate some help.

I have simple app with WebView. And when I click some button or another widget on page, opened in WebView, this button is highlighted like this (not my screenshot, just an example)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ5dt.png)

Can I disable this highlight or change color to transparent?

Comment: Welcome! As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.